# Using different thumbnail for prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

Using prettyPhoto, I was wondering if it's possible to have a different "thumbnail" than the actual image being displayed when I click on the  link (to which the thumbnail is "attached" via an  tag inside the  construct)?

In other words, I have the rel="prettyPhoto" on the  construct, so prettyPhoto will (single image) display whatever I have attached to the href. But I'd like for a separate ICON to be used as the thumbnail instead of a thumbnail of the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Well, duh! :-)

Yes, by doing:

```
<a href="url_to_be_displayed_by_prettyPhoto" rel="prettyPhoto">
  <img src="url_to_thumbnail_or_icon" />
</a>
```

I need more caffeine!